# Bing Speech API / Speech service on Xamarin (No REST, sdk web socket to handle continous recognition)

Tags: azure, xamarin, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, bing-speech

I'm evaluating "Bing Speech API" and its new brother "Speech Service" (still in preview mode) for a simple voice recognition mobile application based on Xamarin.

I've obtained good results using the API REST but it has a constraint duration length of 15 seconds that make it hard to apply for continuous voice recognition and wake word.

Due to this reason I've also explored Bing Speech and Speech Service SDKs based on web socket (also knows as client library). 
They work well on desktop application but they seem to not be compatible with Xamarin (see picture below).

Do you know any possible way to use Bing Speech API or Spech Service client library (Web Socket) to handle a continuous voice recognition in a Xamarin project ?

The only alternative I've found at the moment is move away from Xamarin and use the dedicated Bing Speech API/Speech Service client library for Android and IoS...

Thanks

[Bing Speech API client library on xamarin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj1BR.png)

[Speech Service client library on Xamarin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIexO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Xamarin is currently not supported by Speech SDK. It is on our feature list, but we do not have ETA for that yet.

Thanks,